# What's a POLISH dill pickle"

Tags: pickles

I'm 81 and have not been living in a cave all my life, BUT I had never heard of a "Polish dill pickle" until  today. So, let me now ask, What's the difference between a dill pickle and a Polish dill pickle?
Sun Nov 10, 2019, 11:00 a.m.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Letting us know where your cave is may help, answers may differ a lot depending on where you are in the world.

Comment: Welcome! The good news is that we already have a Q/A that should explain the difference.

Comment: Gee, the comments keep getting dumber  and dumber. Well, I won't be dumb enough to stick around. This site is obviously a waste of time, and I won't be wasting anymore time here. Bye